# fancybox open gallery with doubleclick

Tags: jquery, fancybox, gallery, fancybox-2, double-click

Is there a way to open a gallery with double-clik instead of single click ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 

    $('.fancybox').dblclick( function(){          
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            loop: false,
            padding : 0,
        });
    });
});

<a title="" href="http://url.com/my-image-big.jpg" rel="gallery1" class="fancybox">
  <img src="my-image-small.jpg">
</a>
<a title="" href="http://url.com/my-image-big.jpg" rel="gallery1" class="fancybox">
  <img src="my-image-small.jpg">
</a>
....
```

This obviously doesn't work as expected, but is there something that will work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to manually build your gallery before you can fire it after a `double-click` event.

To build your gallery on-the-fly, you need to use `.each()` to also bind the `index` of each element so the gallery opens from the double-clicked element instead of the first.

Also, you can bind several events using jQuery `.on()` so try this :

```
var gallery = []; // array of gallery elements
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox").each(function (i) {
        gallery.push(this.href); // push element to the array

        // bind your click and double-click events
        $(this).on({
            click: function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            },
            dblclick: function (event) {
                $.fancybox(gallery, {
                    // API options
                    padding: 0,
                    index: i // starts gallery from (double) clicked element
                });
            }
        });
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jqs0je8m/1/)**

Comment: This is ingenious - really. I thought of building array but wasnt able to figure out how to start gallery from clicked element.... now i know :) THANKS A LOT JFK !

Comment: I want to open the fancybox on a single-click. How can this be achieved? And so that you know , I haven't used an special code to make it work on a double-click.

Answer (score 0):

The folllowing snippet shows your code is working. I guess there is another click() trigger bound to .fancybox elsewhere, which is called after yours, superseding your preventDefault() on the click event.

```js
$('.fancybox').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
});

$('.fancybox').dblclick(function(){
  $('#displayme').show();
});
```

```css
#displayme{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="fancybox" href="#" >Fancybox link</a>
<p id="displayme">Hellow I'm a FancyBox</p>
```

Comment: If you read question carefully - it says that it needs to open "Gallery". This code DOESN'T work with gallery !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code will help you:
http://jsfiddle.net/st34o7gw/

```
$('.open_fancybox').on('click',function (e) {              
    e.preventDefault();
});
$(".open_fancybox").dblclick(function() {

$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg',                
        title : '1st title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg',                
        title : '2nd title'
    },
    {
        href : 'http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/3_b.jpg',                
        title : '3rd title'
    }
], {
    padding : 0
});

return false;

});
```

Comment: I got one that as well, but the thing is if I click image 5, slideshow opens from the first image in JS array... and default is to open on the clicked image, right ? I really need something that will prevent click and allow doubleclick retaining all other functionality.