# How to open fancybox3 only on doubleclick?

Tags: html, jquery, fancybox, double-click

I'm looking for a way to open a fancybox gallery just by double clicking for a grid of sortable images. The reason for this desirable behaviour is that I want to focus on one of the images with a single click so that it can be re-sorted with keyboard commands (and not just drag and drop).

I tried unsuccessfully to solve this problem with the `onclick` and `ondbclick` parameters within the `<a>` tag. On [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0L3m1fza/14/) I give an example: For the first image (the bluish one) a single click focuses on the element, but a double click does not open the gallery. For the second image a single click opens the gallery, but I can't focus on the element without opening the gallery. (Image 3 and 4 are for reference only):

```
    <ul id="sortable" class="sortable ui-sortable">
      <li id="obj_01" class="ui-state-default" onclick="this.focus()">
        <a tabindex="-1" data-fancybox="gallery" onclick="return false" ondblclick="location=this.href" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_b.jpg">
          <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="obj_02" class="ui-state-default" onclick="this.focus()">
        <a tabindex="-1" data-fancybox="gallery" href="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_b.jpg">
          <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/1_s.jpg" />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li id="obj_03" class="ui-state-default" onclick="this.focus()">3</li>
      <li id="obj_04" class="ui-state-default" onclick="this.focus()">4</li>
    </ul>
```

I was also not able to get the accepted solution presented at [fancybox open gallery with doubleclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193531/fancybox-open-gallery-with-doubleclick/26193645) to work.

Since I am new to JS/jquery and not very proficient in HTML is there an 'easy' way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to detect double-click by yourself and then just start fancybox using API